# How to reverse Array of Data in Laravel when using Eloquent with Pagination?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am fetching a list of data using Eloquent method and trying to reverse the order of array, I am getting an error.

Here is the code :(Previous Code)

```
$temp = Product::paginate(20);
```

New Code

```
$temp = Product::paginate(20)->orderBy('id','desc');
```

Error :

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.
```

New method :

```
$temp = Product::paginate(20)->sortDesc();
```

Error :

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends does not exist.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to write it in this way,
use orderBy before the paginate

```
$temp = Product::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 2):

use below syntax

```
Product::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Always explain your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

->latest() fetches the most recent set of data from the Database. In short, it sorts the data fetched, using the 'created_at' column to chronologically order the data.

```
Product::latest()->paginate(20)
```

Comment: That is not the question, the question is to order the result with `orderBy` . `latest()` will work for an order on id, but since he is calling the functions in the wrong order, this is not the needed answer.